# Can a XML file be generated for an iPhone view?

Tags: iphone, xml

Can a XML file be generated for an iPhone view?

The view may contain any iPhone control.

Comment: Are you looking for how this can be done?  http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchXML is what I use to do XML parsing. I may not understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. InterfaceBuilder generate XML for visual componens, and save this xml to .xib file.

If you want to do this work manualy, why not ))))

Comment: HI Oxigen,
what should i do if i want to send the xml through a webservice during runtime?

Comment: In runtime.... In runtime application works with non-xml .nib files
You can create xib on server, convert it to nib, download it, and work with this nib (initWithNibName). If you find xib-format description and xib-nib convertor....

Or you can develope your own xml parser and create UI manualy in code.... 
 ((((